# Richtext to MIME....CKeditor

Tags: xpages

I have my backend that is a RichText field (without STORE MIME CONTENT)

If I input this field into Notes Client (compiling richtext field)

and after go in Xpages UI...I see HTML of the field correctly and I different scenario:

- If I do not modify the field and Save the datasource...my backend is RichText normal
- If I go into Ckeditor and insert a new word...and Save the datasource...my backend is RichText MIME
- If I set my backend RichText field with the STORE MIME CONTENT....when I save new document the Xpages runtime go in a error

Have someone any idea to store my backend always with MIME or RICHTEXT?

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel,

- If you don't modify the field in the XPage, it isn't send back to the server and remains untouched on the document. So if your original field contained richtext, it remains rich text.
- If you edit the field in an XPage using CKEditor the contents will always be transformed to MIME (you get a warning upon saving that this will happen).

The "Store contents as MIME" setting will have the effect that the contents of documents created in the client will always be stored as MIME. Is that what you want?

Mark

Comment: Sorry Mark,but if I go in edit Mode of my datasource and Save the datasource why isn't send back to the server?
I would save the field always as "MIME content"..but if I enable this flag into a RichText inside the Form in Designer...and if you create a New Document after you press SAVE button (that save the data source) XPages go in error Runtime (say: Xpages Runtime Error BodyField exist...blalblallbla)

Comment: On submission of an XPage containing a RT field (rendered with the CKEditor) a call is made to a .isModified() function. This in turn calls the checkDirty() function of the CKEditor to check if the contents of the editor have changed (compared to the contents that were loaded on startup). The result of this check is written to a field with the name "<yourRTField>_mod" and send back to the server ("true" or "false"). If the contents haven't changed, the RT field remains untouched in the document. I have seen the runtime error in the past, but can't reproduce it in 8.5.3. Are you running 8.5.3?

Comment: Tnx you much for the clarification!

Yes I use 8.5.3 enviroment...and the problem persist